# LG G3 Verizon, No Boot

Tags: boot, lg, verizon

Last night I was using my Verizon G3, fully updated, not rooted, and it shut off and won't come back on.  If I remove the battery it will begin to boot then go to black screen before it gets to the "Verizon" screen.  The battery had about 40% charge left when it went off.

I can get to the system recovery screen.  Plugging it in prevents it from even beginning to boot and if I plug it in when it's on the system recovery screen it stops working then goes to black screen after a few seconds.  I've selected clear cache, factory reset and safe mode, none of which works.  Every time it begins to do something then goes to black.

The phone is almost 2 years old, I know I should upgrade but I'd really like this phone to work a bit longer before I get a new phone.  I've not had any issues with the phone recently other than the occasional slow-down that restarting would remedy.

The only recent app install was one I installed earlier that day from the play store called "Spread Sign" which is a sign language dictionary that was recommended to me and is very highly rated and seems completely legit. I've not heard of it causing issues with other or on my LG tablet and it had been working fine for hours before it shut down.

Comment: New symptom, now when I get it to the system recovery screen, the top of the screen is a little lighter than the rest and it's 'flashing' or 'blinking' really fast.  It almost looks streaked at the top.

Comment: Sounds like hardware problem, some shorts in the motherboard as it start acting weirdly whenever you plug it